# How to setup laravel 10 and vue 3 and connect with route?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I am using laravel 10 and vue 3.I successfully set up it, after add @vite('resource/js/app.js') its works fine.but when i try to connect route then it does not work.I don't know what is the problem.Please give me solution.[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRaOj.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ4p5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P5SI.png)

i need to solve this problem

Comment: How is your Laravel routing setup?

Comment: don't post code as image.